# Pass an array argument to custom pig loader

Tags: user-defined-functions, apache-pig

I wrote a LoadFunc function that allows me to select given keywords of an unstructured huge log-file. How do I pass Tuple into my function as an argument?

Something like

```
A = load '/input/*' using MyLoader('keyword1','keyword2');
```

or

```
A = load '/input/*' using MyLoader( ('keyword1','keyword2') );
```

cause errors:

```
grunt> a = LOAD '/input/*' USING MyLoader( ('keyword1','keyword2') );     
2012-08-28 19:44:04,331 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 3, column 36>  mismatched input '(' expecting RIGHT_PAREN
Details at logfile: /home/hadoop/pig-0.10.0/pig_1346159261142.log
```

Comment: maybe i am wrong.. as i am also new.. but in pig you can pass only one argument.. and that argument is a tuple so based on my little knowledge..you will have .. using MyLoader( keyword) and this keyword will be a tuple and you will handle this tuple where you write udf function?

Comment: Fraz, could you supply a sample code please. I can't write hardcoded tuple, but only create from data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In practice, a Pig LoadFunc can only accept String parameters for its constructor. See http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/pig-user/201302.mbox/%3CCAO8ATY27UOdcgSjdh19F=iHsnFEAwmzedWbsnZ66sNvcsjfgog@mail.gmail.com%3E.

For your purposes, I would pass a CSV as a String to your LoadFunc and then parse it within the LoadFunc's constructor.